# How to recive more than 65000 bytes in C++ socket using recv()

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, tcp, serversocket

I am developing a client server application (TCP) in Linux using C++. I want to send more than `65,000` bytes at the same time. In TCP, the maximum packet size is `65,535` bytes only.

**How can I send the entire bytes without loss?**

Following is my code at server side.

```
//Receive the message from client socket
if((iByteCount = recv(GetSocketId(), buffer, MAXRECV, MSG_WAITALL)) > 0) 
{
     printf("\n Received bytes %d\n", iByteCount);

     SetReceivedMessage(buffer);
     return LS_RESULT_OK;
}
```

If I use `MSG_WAITALL` it takes a long time to receive the bytes so how can I set the flag to receive more than 1 million bytes at time.

Edit: The MTU size is 1500 bytes but the absolute limitation on TCP Packet size if 65,535.

Comment: TCP is designed to hide the IP packet size as an implementation detail of transmission. Routers can split the packets and otherwise munge them. Are you really sure you want to rely on one huge, 100KB packet getting across a network without being chopped up?

Comment: TCP is a stream protocol, don't try to treat it as fixed-size packets. Receive however many bytes you can, process those - the sooner you learn to accept this is how to deal with TCP, the happier you will be :-)

Comment: What do you mean by "**lakhs** bytes"?

Comment: i need to send more than 1000000 bytes to server ,when i sent 65 ,635 or 100000 bytes it's working properly, if i send more than that there is loss in my data....so how can i handle that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that your problem is related to kernel socket buffer sizes. Try adding the following to your code:

```
int buffsize = 1024*1024;
setsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &buffsize, sizeof(buffsize));
```

You might need to increase some sysctl variables too:

```
sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=8388608
sysctl -w net.core.wmem_max=8388608
```

Note however, that relying on TCP to fill your whole buffer is generally a bad idea. You should rather call recv() multiple times. The only good reason why you would want to receive more than 64K is for improved performance. However, Linux should already have auto-tuning that will progressively increase the buffer sizes as required.

Comment: ya i already try this,that could not work,actually i need to send one 800kb file,through socket communication to the server ,when 1 send morethan 80kb ,it could not send properly it only sent 65635 bytes or sometime below that range,i can't get the exact data at my server side .whethere the fault is in my client side or sever side...

Comment: His problem is that he doesn't understand the API or the protocol. Raising the socket buffers is generally a good idea but it doesn't actually solve any specific difficulty that has been expressed in this thread.

Answer (score 9):

Judging from the comments above, it seems you don't understand how `recv` works, or how it is supposed to be used.

You **really** want to call `recv` in a loop, until either you know that the expected amount of data has been received or until you get a "zero bytes read" result, which means the other end has closed the connection. Always, no exceptions.

If you need to do other things concurrently (likely, with a server process!) then you will probably want to check descriptor readiness with `poll` or `epoll` first. That lets you multiplex sockets as they become ready.

The reason why you want to do it that way, and never any different, is that you don't know how the data will be packeted and how (or when) packets will arrive. Plus, `recv` gives no guarantee about the amount of data read at a time. It will offer what it has in its buffers at the time you call it, no more and no less (it may block if there's nothing, but then you *still* don't have a guarantee that any particular amount of data will be returned when it resumes, it may still return e.g. 50 bytes!).

Even if you only send, say, 5,000 bytes total, it is perfectly valid behaviour for TCP to break this into 5 (or 10, or 20) packets, and for `recv` to return 500 (or 100, or 20, or 1) bytes at a time, every time you call it. *That's just how it works.*
TCP guarantees that anything you send will eventually arrive at the other end or produce an error. And, it guarantees that whatever you send arrives in order. It does not guarantee much else. Above all, it does not guarantee that any particular amount of data is ready at any given time.
You must be prepared for that, and the only way to do it is calling `recv` repeatedly. Otherwise you will always lose data under some circumstances.

`MSG_WAITALL` should in principle make it work the way you expect, but that is *bad* behaviour, and it is not guaranteed to work. If the socket (or some other structure in the network stack) runs against a soft or hard limit, it may not, *and probably will not* fulfill your request. Some limits are obscure, too. For example, the number for `SO_RCVBUF` must be *twice as large* as what you expect to receive under Linux, because of implementation details.

Correct behaviour of a server application should **never** depend on assumptions such as "it fits into the receive buffer". Your application needs to be prepared, in principle, to receive terabytes of data using a 1 kilobyte receive buffer, and in chunks of 1 byte at a time, if need be. A larger receive buffer will make it more efficient, but that's it... it still has to work either way.

The fact that you only seee failures upwards of some "huge" limit is just luck (or rather, bad luck). The fact that it apparently "works fine" up to that limit suggests what you do is correct, but it isn't. It's an unlucky coincidence that it works.

**EDIT:**
As requested in below comment, here is what this could look like (*Code is obviously untested, caveat emptor.*)

```
std::vector<char> result;
int size;

char recv_buf[250];

for(;;)
{
    if((size = recv(fd, recv_buf, sizeof(recv_buf), 0)) > 0)
    {
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            result.push_back(recv_buf[i]);
    }
    else if(size == 0)
    {
        if(result.size() < expected_size)
        {
            printf("premature close, expected %u, only got %u\n", expected_size, result.size());
        }
        else
        {
            do_something_with(result);
        }
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        perror("recv");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

That will receive any amount of data you want (or until `operator new` throws `bad_alloc` after allocating a vector several hundred MiB in size, but that's a different story...).

If you want to handle several connections, you need to add `poll` or `epoll` or `kqueue` or a similar functionality (or... `fork`), I'll leave this as exercise for the reader.

Comment: could u some post the code  for recv  functions which receive the more than 50kb data using recv() in c++,

Answer (score 3):

> in tcp max packet sixe is 65,635,bytes

No it isn't. TCP is a byte-stream protocol over segments over IP packets, and the protocol has unlimited transmission sizes over any one connection. Look at all those 100MB downloads: how do you think they work?

Just send and receive the data. You'll get it.

Comment: For clarity:  the maximum size of an IP packet (without the "jumbo payload" option) is 65535 bytes, but TCP divides your data into as many IP packets as necessary to send it all.

Comment: ya i know,but max size per packet is 65635bytes,if the size is exists it should be send over another packet, now my problem is how to receive the data using that recv() ,if i declare the buffer size is char buffer[1000000],like and set flag as MSG_WAITALL then only i get entire bytes even though i lossed some of bytes,i alredy set the delimeter at end of my messge,if any other way to recv the data without lossing

Comment: this is my recv  function  recv(GetSocketId(), buffer,MAXRECV,MSG_WAITALL)) > 0)  in that i use buffer size as 1000000,so i tooks long time to recv the all data ,so i need some anothe way for that,could u suggest

Comment: `MSG_WAITALL` is for when you know the exact size of the message -- the call will not return before either the connection is terminated or the buffer is full. You want to use `recv()` in a loop, handling data as it comes in.

Comment: could u some post the code for recv functions which receive the more than 50kb data using recv() in c++,

Comment: @Mr.Cool Err, put it into a loop? Is this so hard?

Comment: @EJP if i using loop the server always wait for client data even client sent entire data to server,so my problem is now i cant process my messsage

Comment: @Mr.Cool The idea is that you stop reading when you have received the entire message you are trying to read, and then process it. How you know that depends on how the message is structured, e.g. a length word at the start, or STX/ETX, or a self-describing protocol such as XML.

Comment: @Mr.Cool It's really this simple: If you want to receive more data, call `recv`. If not, don't.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest exploring kqueue or something similar.  With event notification there is no need to loop on `recv` .  Just call a simple read function upon an `EV_READ` event and use a single call to the `recv` function upon the socket that triggered the event.  Your function can have a buffer size of 10 bytes or however much you want it doesn't matter because if you did not read the entire message the first time around you'll just get another EV_READ event on the socket and you recall your read function.  When the data is read you'll get a EOF event.  No need to hustle with loops that may or may not block other incoming connections.