# How to receive more than 40Kb in C++ socket using read()

Tags: c++, sockets, buffer

I am developing a client-server application (TCP) in Linux using C++. This application is in charge of testing the network performance.
The connection between client and server is established only once, and then data are transmitted/received using `write()/read()` with an own-defined protocol.

When data exceeds 40Kb I receive just a part of the data only once. (i.e. I receive about 48KB)

Please find down the relevant part of the code:

```
while (1) {
        servMtx.lock();
        ...
        serv_bytes = (byte *) malloc(size_bytes);
        n = read(newsockfd, serv_bytes,size_bytes);
        if (n != (int)size_bytes ) {
            std::cerr << "No enough data available for msg. Received just: " << n << std::endl;
            continue;
        }
        receivedBytes += n + size_header_bytes + sizeof(ssize_t);
        ....
}
```

I increased the kernel buffer size to become 1MB using:

```
int buffsize = 1024*1024;
setsockopt(newsockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVBUF, &buffsize, sizeof(buffsize));
```

and modified sysctl variables too:

sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=8388608;
sysctl -w net.core.wmem_max=8388608;

as mentioned on this [How to recive more than 65000 bytes in C++ socket using recv()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920171/how-to-recive-more-than-65000-bytes-in-c-socket-using-recv) but nothing was changed. Also, I tried to change the package size to no avail.

Comment: Your code is wrong. `n < size_bytes` is *not* an error condition when `n > 0` and it is a very common case.

Comment: As you know, read() either handles (and waits) for 'size_bytes' (i.e. n == (int)size_bytes) or returns an error.

Comment: By the way, data are sent correctly without any problem. And I am always receiving the same exact number of bytes :/

Comment: @Mohamad-JaafarNehme That is completely incorrect, and it is the cause of your problem. It blocks until *at least one* byte has arrived, or end of stream or an error. See the *man* page. You have to *loop.* It's a byte-stream protocol, not a messaging protocol.

Comment: @Mohamad-JaafarNehme: because you have been unlucky.

Comment: 2. I am sending just arbitrary data like this: "memset (text, '.', sz);"

Comment: 3. As I already mentioned, yes I am sending stream of bytes of my own-defined protocol over TCP

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch :D

Comment: @Mohamad-JaafarNehme You're not reading carefully. I said '*at least one* byte', and I put it in italics too. If more than one byte arrives while it is blocking you will get all the bytes that have arrived.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should `read` or `recv` in *several chunks* (in general; if you are unlucky, the "several" becomes "one"). So you need to manage your buffering and keep (and use) the count of received bytes.

So at some point, you'll code

```
int nbrecv = recv(s, buffer + off, bufsize, 0);
if (nbrec>0) { off += nbrecv; bufsize -= nbrecv; }
```

and you probably should do that in your [event loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) (often around [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)...). And it does happen that `nbrec` is a lot less than `bufsize` and you should be handling that common case.

[TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) does not guarantee that you'll get all the bytes in the same `recv`! It could depend on external factors (routing, network hardware, ...); it is a stream-oriented protocol, not a message-packet one. If your application wants *messages* it should buffer the input and chunk that input into messages according to the content. Look at [HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) or [SMTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol): their message have a well defined boundary given by header information (`Content-Length:` in HTTP) or by ending convention (line with a single `.` in SMTP).

Please read carefully [read(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html), [recv(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html), [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html), [tcp(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html), some [sockets tutorial](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm), [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

Comment: @Mohamad-JaafarNehme Your comment doesn't make sense. He hasn't said anything about deleting old data, and there is no such thing as a message in TCP.

Comment: @Mohamad-JaafarNehme It's true all right. It's in the *man* pages cited above. You simply have *no valid reason* to disbelieve it. And 'nested loop' such as *what?* Who said anything about nested loops? Your comments here still aren't making sense.